# Normed Space with Closure & Complement

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let A be a subset of a normed space $X$. Define $A^{\bot}:=\{f\in X' | f(x)=0 $ for all $x\in A\}$. Show that $A^{\bot}$ is closed subspace of $X'$ and $A^{\bot}=(\bar{A})^{\bot}$.

Help me please!

Comment: You should probably mention what is $X'$ and what topology on $X'$ you are using. (At least if you want to reasonably speak about closure and closed subset of $X'$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(f_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $A^{\perp}$ and denote the limit of this sequence by $f$.

For $x \in A$ we have:

$|f(x)|=|f(x)-f_n(x)| \le ||f-f_n||*||x||$.

Since $||f-f_n|| \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$, we get $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in A$, thus $f \in A^{\perp}$ and therefore $A^{\perp}$  is closed.

Its now your turn to show that $A^{\bot}=(\bar{A})^{\bot}$